# Uninstalled unity-greeter and then installed it again, but desktop is gone

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, unity-greeter

Will Ubuntu be the at the same status after I deinstall and reinstall the same package?

I deinstalled the `unity-greeter` package with `apt-get remove` and I reinstalled it with `apt-get install`.

So I think Ubuntu should be the same, because I used remove, that means I didn't deinstall the dependencies and other related data. And since install will check if the dependencies already exist, so it will only install the `unity-greeter` package again. But after doing so I have no desktop any more, just blank wallpaper.

What can I do to reverse this or find another method to repair it?

My Ubuntu is 14.04

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If you reinstalled the packages which you removed, the behaviour should be same as before the removal of that package. If you purged (removed configuration as well) then it would be like it was never configured and will lokk like a fresh package. Anyways, FYI: Ubuntu 14.04 is going EOL in 3 days. So, it's better to upgrade to a supported release, i.e. 16.04 or 18.04+

Comment: Many package management operation are not simply reversible. I have completely destroyed my system before by uninstalling certain packages and recovery was a lot harder than reinstalling